# как грамотно хранить в сессии? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, сессия

хранить какие-то данные которые привязаны к авторизации?
к примеру когда залогинился пользоваватель тогда храним данные вышел все удалим?
или просто хранить независимо от авторизации? как правильно или можно по разному?

Comment: Laravel под капотом сам хранит сессию авторизованного пользователя

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. При чем тут аутентификация пользователя? Что нужно, то и храните в сессии. Документация: [Сессия HTTP](https://docs.rularavel.com/docs/8.x/session). Только, в сессии и так много чего хранится. Например, после аутентификации к данным пользователя можно обратиться [Auth::user()](https://docs.rularavel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user).